# What happens to anonymous functions when no longer used?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, garbage-collection

I'm loading content dynamically via **AJAX** (following a "[hijax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijax)" pattern), and sometimes the AJAX loaded content has scripts that I also load and execute (inline, external). The scripts I load (written by me) are all wrapped up inside of an anonymous function (each separate script in a separate anonymous function) `(function(){}());`.

Thing is, since all is done via AJAX, the page never truly reloads completely, and as far as I'm aware, these anonymous functions just linger in the window object, inaccessible, when the content changes and the previously loaded scripts are no longer relevant.

**Is this what happens? Or do they get cleaned up by the browser's garbage collector?** I imagine that if they just linger in there, over time, the page would get slow, because of all the anonymous functions that are sitting in there, being useless.

And if that was the case, would wrapping all of my scripts in a variable and with each new AJAX request clearing that variable with something like `myScripts = undefined` be enough?

Thanks.

Comment: if you bind to the dom inside the anons, they might not get collected. normal pure functions will be garbage collected.

Comment: "Binding to the DOM" as in storing references to DOM elements in variables (inside of the anonymous function) and adding event listeners?

Comment: yes, exactly... jQuery in particular is really hard to "re-init" due to un-reachable ready(fn) calls

Comment: Even if the referenced DOM elements are no longer in the DOM? I do a lot of DOM manipulation inside of these functions, so I guess they might not be getting collected at all. Aaah jQuery, I'm not using it for this project right now.

Comment: it's hard to generalize on specifics, but you can use the profiler and the chrome task manager to determine if there's a problem with what you're doing now...

Comment: Well, with a Chrome heap snapshot, I did notice a bunch of objects in 'red', which I read means that they are referencing to detached DOM elements (just right now I searched for what red means, but I had noticed the color before). And the retained size sometimes got up to 6,000,000+, which I guess is not a lot, but my project isn't even that complex at the moment. So that raised my concern. And I still don't completely understand how this mumbo jumbo works. I'll keep digging though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Holy crap, I think this is really an issue (that only I care about, however, haha). I just tested some scenarios (really, just clicking links real fast) and I could get the retained size up to 87,000,000+ !